# Mule and org.hibernate.hibernate-validator

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, mule

In the project I'm working on, I have a dependency that requires hibernate-validator to be also included in the project's pom.xml.

I have the following in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

However, in spite of including all of the above as dependencies, when attempting to launch the project in mule, i get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:98) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:423) ~[?:?]
```

Doing further research on SO and other sites, I've tried to work around the issue using several methods including throwing in `java.el-api` (which IIRC isn't actually needed) as well as adding to the `loader.override` property (in mule-deploy.properties) `javax.el.ExpressionFactory` and `org.mule.devkit.model.code.ExpressionFactory`. Adding these classes to `loader.override` only resulted in a "Can't override a system package" error in `mule.log`.

Any ideas what I might be missing? Thanks!

Comment: It may be caused by an old version of javax.el on your classpath. What happens when you include the [javax.el-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/javax.el-api) ?

Maybe an older version is included by one of your dependencies. Can you provide the output of `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` ?

Comment: I also have this problem and have done some investigating but unfortunately do not have a solution.  The problem is caused by javax.el.ExpressionFactory class being present in mule at ${MULE_HOME}/lib/opt/el-api-6.0.45.jar (The tomcat implementation of EL 2.1 Spec).  The Mule class loader always searches for classes in ${MULE_HOME}/lib/opt/ before the actual application jars, therefore it will never find the EL 2.2 implementation of ExpressionFactory class in your application jars.  A loader override would normally be used in this situation but can not be because the class is in javax package